# How to get extjs grid cell component

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to get grid's cell and fire cellclick event on it programmatically. How can I implement it?So far I am successful to get cell's dom element like this

```
var cell = pos.view.getCellByPosition(newPos);
```

but when I execute the following code

```
cell.fireEvent('click');
```

it gives me error because its not Ext Component. Is there any way to get Ext Component from Dom Element. Dom element has an ID but when I use 
`Ext.getCmp(cell.id);`
it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cellclick event is actually fired from the underlying View, not the cell itself.

So try to fire the following event:

```
pos.view.fireEvent("cellclick")
```

You should fill the missing params, as cellclick should deliver the following:

```
cellclick( Ext.view.Table this, HTMLElement td, Number cellIndex,
           Ext.data.Model record, HTMLElement tr, Number rowIndex,
           Ext.EventObject e, Object eOpts )
```

Answer (score 4):

Grid cell has no representation by an ExtJS component therefore you cannot fire event on it. It is possible fire manually DOM event for cell DOM element (http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly) or fire event itemclick for Ext.grid.View component.

Comment: To build on this guy's answer, also since a cell is not a component, what purpose could firing an event from it possibly have?